# Newbie Python - statement being true when 2 specific values occur

Tags: python

I’m extremely new to coding and have tried looking everywhere for an answer to this, I think the problem is I don’t know how to word what I am looking for in my searches.

I have a piece of code:

```
if any (("X" in high_score for high_score in arrangement[0]) and ("Tall" in height for height in arrangement[0])):
        hs_tall = True
```

In this example I am referring to arrangement[0] out of 4 possible arrangements (0, 1, 2, 3). I don’t want to be referring to a specific arrangement like this, rather I want this to be true when X AND Tall both occur together in an arrangement (any of the 4 arrangements).

I’m sorry if this question is too basic for these forums but I have spent all day trying to find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the entire `arrangement` data structure for us to see?

Answer (score 1):

```
any (("X" in high_score for high_score in arrangement[0]) and ("Tall" in height for height in arrangement[0]))
```

is equivalent to

```
any ("Tall" in height for height in arrangement[0])
```

`and` returns the second expression if first expression is "Truthy", in the example below, it doesn't matter if first generator comprehension yields only zeroes or not. It's the second that is evaluated/iterated upon:

```
>>> any((0 for x in range(10)) and range(10))
True
>>> any((0 for x in range(10)) and (0 for x in range(10)))
False
>>> any(range(10) and (0 for x in range(10)))
False
```

What you probably need is calling `any` in each generator comprehension and `and` the results:

You could change the behaviour by using list comprehensions (so a list of 0 would be Falsy, even in first position), but the result still wouldn't be the one you expect.

```
if any ("X" in high_score for high_score in arrangement[0]) and any("Tall" in height for height in arrangement[0])):
```

Aside: given the expression which looks twice in the same structure, the test could probably use some optimization.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice, and yes there's probably a lot of optimization potential. This is my first coding project and my main focus is just to get it to work to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm re-doing a lot of my code and approaching the problem a different way so I don't need this question answered anymore thanks.